# Escape sequence to display apostrophe in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I want to output apostrophe (') in matlab. Some thing like:

```
SendOrder('side, symbol, price', 'b, msft, 10', 'b, ibm, 200')
```

I am not able to do it with the help of disp(). What are escape sequences in matlab?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

try the double apostrophe :

```
''
```